# What's the idiomatic way to remove elements by property from ES6 sets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, set

I've been reading through the set docs here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set.

I have a collection of objects and I think I want to convert them from an object store to a set store.  Let's say I have code like this:

```
var a = {a:1};
var b = {b:2};
var c = {a:1, c:3};

var set = new Set();
set.add(a);
set.add(b);
set.add(c);
```

What's a good, idiomatic way of removing items with `a:1` if I no longer have the original objects?

I came up with this... is this the expected approach?

```
set.forEach(entry => {
  if (entry.a === 1) {
    set.delete(entry);
  }
});
```

More, if I have a very large set (say, 250K elements) and I know just one of them has the property (say, `id:92830932`), I would want to stop iteration once it finds the right one.  Is there some way of doing that more quickly?  Perhaps a while on the `set.values()` iterator or something?

Comment: so, for `entry.a === 1`, what is the entry to delete? `a` or `c`?

Comment: its look like you want to work with Map and not with set  as you are storing objects https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: @AmitWagner I ended up going with a Map as you suggested.  If you make an an answer, I'll vote it.  If not, I'll do it.